# Reminders in Samsung calendar?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar, reminders

Whenever I add a reminder with Google (either from web interface or through assistant) it gets a reminder into my google calendar, which is not visible in Galaxy's calendar.

How can I see these reminders in both Google and Samsung calendar apps?

Comment: I think it's unlikely that the data can be shared with other vendors' apps since it's completely Google products.

Comment: @AndrewT., thats not quite true.  I use Business Calendar, and it syncs with Google just fine (both ways).

Comment: @Daniel, are you wedded to the Samsung Calendar ?

Comment: @RohitGupta fair point, I should have said that it's unlikely for different vendors to cooperate, considering they have their own apps and environment.

Comment: @RohitGupta: I'm using Samsung Calendar on my phone and watch, yes. But sometimes I add reminders on my PC via web broweser to Google Calendar which would be great to see on my phone / watch too.